# Accessing value from dictionary based on every value of for loop in jinja

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am new to jinja and flask

I am trying print all employees information

Users table is having Employee name, dept_id and role_id, code is below:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Department Name</th>
        <th>Employee Role</th>
    </tr>

    {% for emp in employees %}
    {% set dept_name = depts[emp.dept_id] %}
    {% set role_name = roles[emp.role_id] %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ emp.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ dept_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ role_name }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Python:

```
def display_employees():
    employees = Users.query.all()
    departments = Department.query.all()
    depts = {}
    roles = {2: "Manager", 3: "Employee"}
    for dept in departments:
        depts[dept.id] = dept.name

    return render_template(
        "display_employees.html", employees=employees, depts=depts, roles=roles
    )
```

DB:

Department Data:

```
[("7", "Sales"), ("8", "IT")]
```

Users Data:

> [("id", "Name", "Email", "role_id", "dept_id")]

```
[("2", "Anuj Kumar", "anuj.kumar@gmail.com", "2", "8")]
```

NOT ABLE TO DISPLAY dept_name and role_name

Please ask if I forgot to share any information.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please decouple your code from your API/DB by adding some sample data for `employees` and `departments` to make debugging easier.

Comment: @albert , apologies, Forgot to add DB info

Comment: Please do not add the data as images. In order to decouple your code from external dependencies (e.g. data from a DB) and to provide a minimum example, you could mock some data with e.g. dicts. This would make helping you a lot easier and enable other people to investigate your problem...

Comment: @albert , sorry, I have added respective data, please have a look, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using multiple set statements

As it was 2 level accessing of variable

when I was trying `depts.emp.dept_id`, it was saying that emp is not attribute of depts which is true

So, I did as below:

```
{% set emp_role_id, emp_dept_id = emp.role_id, emp.dept_id %}

{% set role_name, dept_name = roles[emp_role_id], depts[emp_dept_id] %}
```

It worked for me, thanks everyone for giving your inputs

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code works as expected for me. So I can't reproduce the behavior.

Still, I wonder why you use dictionaries to get the reference to the department or role.

The following example uses a [relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) to make the referenced department reachable. A property is used to enable access to the name of the role.
So you don't have to create dictionaries and assign variables within the template.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
import random 


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///example.db'
)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    ROLES = {
        2: 'Manager', 
        3: 'Employer'
    }

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)

    dept_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('department.id'))
    dept = db.relationship('Department', backref='users')

    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    
    @property
    def role(self):
        return User.ROLES[self.role_id]

class Department(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)

with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    departments = [Department(name=name) for name in ('Sales', 'IT',)]
    users = [
        User(
            email=f'user-{i}@home.local', 
            name=f'user-{i}', 
            role_id=random.choice(list(User.ROLES.keys())), 
            dept=random.choice(departments)
        ) for i in range(1, 11)
    ]
    db.session.add_all(users)
    db.session.commit()

@app.route('/employees')
def employees():
    users = User.query.all()
    return render_template('employees.html', **locals())
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Employees</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Role</th>
        </tr>
        {% for user in users -%}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.dept.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.role }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor -%}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```